# MySQL with and without Parenthesis giving Different Results

Tags: mysql

I've been working on a MySQL query that is giving me different results.
Can somebody please enlighten me on what is going on.

[image]

[image]

i'll be using this query in a where clause so i will be needing to put parenthesis on it. Is there any work around in this situation?

```
select dodtepost
    from hrxo
    where enccode = '000194100000000007387212/24/201811:32:38'
    and dmdcomb = '000000002379';
```

this gives me 3 results.

```
 (select dodtepost
    from hrxo
    where enccode = '000194100000000007387212/24/201811:32:38'
    and dmdcomb = '000000002379');
```

while this gives none.

Comment: Please paste the queries here as text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: No pictures, thanks.

Comment: put **SELECT * FROM (  yourQuery )** before

Comment: An order by by itself - which is how all your code is will throw an error.

Comment: These queries run by themselves will yield the same result - can you prove otherwise by providing sample data as text?